# How to stub or ignore meteor/session in jest env?

Tags: meteor, jestjs, stub

Jestjs gives me this error when I am testing a react component:

---

`import {Session} from 'meteor/session' ". The error is "Cannot find module 'meteor/session' "`

---

**myTestFile**

```
import PlanSetup from "../../../ui/pages/planSetup/planSetup";

let PlanSetupWrapper;
const PlansetupProps={
    name: "string",
    budget: "string",
    lang: { english: "en",
               French : "fr"
             }
};


describe('<PlanSetup />', () => {
    PlanSetupWrapper = mount(<PlanSetup {...PlansetupProps}/>);
    it('All child components renders correctly', () => {
 expect(PlanSetupWrapper).toMatchSnapshot();
});
});
```

Comment: Hi Megha, welcome to SO! Could you please provide your relevant code? Something like the content of the file you're testing, and the test case would help a lot!

Comment: have you installed meteor? ie. `npm install --save-dev meteor`

Comment: The component which i import i.e PlanSetup is using the session from meteor/session. But jest couldn't able to find the session, how can i provide this to my testing environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
**jest.config.js**
module.exports = {
    moduleNameMapper: {
      "^meteor/(.*)": "<rootDir>/imports/tests/mocks/meteor.js"
    },
    transform: {
        "^.+\\.(js|jsx)?$": "babel-jest",
        ".+\\.(css|styl|less|sass|scss)$": "/home/megha/Megha/TVStack/dan-tvstack-ui/node_modules/jest-css-modules-transform",
    },
    moduleFileExtensions: [
      'js',
      'jsx'

    ],
    modulePaths: [
        "<rootDir>/node_modules/"
      ],
    globals: {
              "window": true
            },

    unmockedModulePathPatterns: [
      '/^imports\\/.*\\.jsx?$/'
    ],
    setupFiles: [
              "<rootDir>/setupTests.js"
            ]
  };


**<rootDir>/imports/tests/mocks/meteor.js**

exports._session = {
    __: function(value) { return value }
  };
```

Comment: Way to go @megha-rawat

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow @MeghaRawat. There are a couple of things to consider here.

1) Keeping your components pure
2) Mocking up Meteor services

What this means is that any React components should be as pure as possible, and not reference Meteor - the containers should do that, and pass props to the components.

Jest doesn't know about Meteor, so any Meteor features will need to be stubbed, to prevent the the kind of problems you are encountering.

I may be able to find some code to help you if you need it.

Comment: Thanks @Mikkel. I mocked the meteor/session and added it in "moduleNameMapper" in my jest config. And it's done.